# Automate validation of result based on auto clicking a button

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, ui-automation

There is a button on a webpage, If I click that button first time, it takes some time to get the status in progress. once it is in progress then If I click after sometime say 3 minutes then the status is coming as successful.

The problem here is I have to give sleep time between two clicks to verify the status and sometimes because of this sleep time, a status not in sync. For example I click a button and status in progress and if I click after 3 minutes, sometimes status is successful or sometimes it remains in progress which is failing my TC.

isn't there any way that button should be clicked automatically until status comes in progress and then I can verify the status. same for successful status as well.

I am using sleep between two clicks

```
    browser.sleep(25000) 

    button.click();
    expect(inprogress_class.getText()).toContain('in progress');

    browser.sleep(100000) // waiting for a defined time to click a buttonassuming that status will be successful

    button.click();
    expect(successful_class.getText()).toContain('successful);
```

Expected: Button keeps on getting clicked until status changes

Actual: giving sleep time between click and waiting for status to change

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option

To click for the first time and wait for `InProgress` State

```
await button.click();
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(await inprogress_class), 25000, 'The wait for inProgress state');
```

To click the button until we get the success try the below one

```
 while (await successful_class.getText() !== 'successful') {
  await button.click();
  await browser.sleep(10000); // update the time with how often the button needs to be clicked
 }
 expect(await successful_class.getText()).toContain('successful);
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: This is same. Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

If you can use async/await then it would be more easier otherwise you will have to use Promises chaining.

try with async/await approach :

```
await browser.wait(async () => {
        await button.click();
        var buttonText = await inprogress_class.getText();
        return buttonText === 'in progress';
       }, 180000); 
expect(inprogress_class.getText()).toContain('in progress');

await browser.wait(async () => {
        await button.click();
        var buttonText = await successful_class.getText();
        return buttonText === 'successful';
       }, 180000); 
expect(successful_class.getText()).toContain('successful);
```

Comment: I used it but got a message that unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.